# iOS 11 app icon fade out ( whitish ). Not the right color

Tags: ios, appicon

When installing our application in any apple device with version 11.0 or higher the icon seems to be faded. The right dark purple background is not appearing and instead is replaced by a kind of whitish purple, it seems like faded. There is no alphas in the png file. (Developing with the latest Xcode Version 9.1)

Comment: Just a sanity check - can you confirm that it is not an issue of screen brightness settings and/or night shift?

Comment: There is no issue with the brightness. I have double check in several phones, and the ones with iOS 11.0 or higher display the faded icon instead of the right one. Whereas the other devices with lower ios versions display the correct one.

Comment: Same issue here, I have taken a screenshot and analyzed the color values on the pixels, they are faded/washed; I tried rbg and srgb - iOS12; works fine on simulator, faded on device